# Docker swarm - Finding correct swarm.Version when updating services

Tags: docker, containers, scale, docker-swarm

I want to scale the number of replicas on a service using the Go SDK.

This is the function that (I think) accomplishes this:

```
func (cli *Client) ServiceUpdate(ctx context.Context, serviceID string, version swarm.Version, service swarm.ServiceSpec, options types.ServiceUpdateOptions) (types.ServiceUpdateResponse, error)
```

Whenever I run it, however, I get an error:

```
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = update out of sequence
```

I'm pretty sure this occurs because [the update sequence is out of order](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30794#issuecomment-411137766), and the version no. is used to order this.

But I don't know how to find the right version index!

Answer (score 1):

Ah I figured it out!

Docker requires that you pass the same version and ServiceSpec when updating a service to avoid out-of-sequence updates, which was the issue I ran into.

You can easily get this through ServiceInspectWithRaw, which returns a swarm.Service, which has a version in its Meta.Version field. I totally missed that beforehand.